# I am having a problem passing arguments to execvp using sleep and fork

Tags: sleep, execvp

I asked a really terrible question last time so I will try and do better here.  I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int forkChild;
    char* argList[] = {"10","20","30"};

    forkChild = fork();

    if(forkChild == 0)
    {
        execvp("sleep",argList);

        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

I am having trouble getting the execvp line to work.  It will not sleep at all.  It seems that the trouble might be because the argList array is passing strings and not integers to execvp.  If I plug an integer directly into sleep it seems to work fine.

Eventually my program should be able to pass any parameter to execvp, so I am not sure why there is a problem with argument types.  Is there something to this that I am not seeing? 
Thanks

Comment: The second parameter to `execvp` must be an array of pointers whose end is indicated by a null pointer.

Comment: thanks.  that seemed to solve the problem.  However, now when I try and print multiple lines using multiple calls to printf, only the first line prints.